# Marriage in islam

Tags: nikah

Aslmkm,

Please help me out.past from four months iam in a dilemma...dnt know what to do.
 Mine is a love marriage..me and my husband married past from 12 years...he loves me so much...but the thing is he got married again four months back without  my knowledge later on I came to know about this...when I asked he said he married her just to give shelter and only for the sake of Islam, fearing Allah... he married. He is asking sorry for whatever he has done and want to continue his marriage..he doesn't want  to  leave her..also  he is asking me to continue  our marriage bcoz he loves me so much..what should I do in this matter iam deeply hurt by his extreme step..iam in a shock still..its like my life has come to halt.dont have any idea what should I do...please help in this regard...

Jazakallh

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, you stand for yourself, this thing that is done to you is just unfair. I mean, he should've asked for your permission; he's your lover and husband though. So, I think if you love and appreciate his love so much, you can cope with it anyway, but if you get this thing as a betrayal, just divorce legally.

Comment: @Downvoter care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't like it either (that he did it secretly from the wife), it is not betrayal, just a blame on his behalf. Of course he knew she never allow it. Patience is the key. I recommend you to read Surah Talaq (65) and Tahrim (66). No not for preparing divorce, no. Trust me you'll feel better, especially if you understand the meanings.

According to Sheik Dr. Zakir Naik. In marriage contract, wife can add a clause for stipulation about marrying another wife. i.e. "He cannot marry another woman as long as I'm alive."

It's little bit too late for this sister, but other sisters who will marry can think about this.

May Allah (swt) helps us all.